# WCF error: The socket connection was aborted

Tags: c#, sockets, wcf, net-tcp

I host WCF connection using `topshelf` and service configurations use behavior and tcp connection like the following :

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MetaDataBehvior">
      <serviceMetadata />
    </behavior>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <!--Transport security is enabled Because all machinses on the same Domain (intranet) -->
        <!-- http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/wcf-transport-security/ -->
        <!--Transport security is enabled-->
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
                    protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I tried even using throttling but nothing change after several usages of the service I got the error :

One or more errors occurred.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9844041'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9844041'.

any advice how to trace or fix this

Answer (score 0):

WCF contains a few classes that you can use to trace/debug your application

The first would be enabling Trace logging/message logging, you can use the SvcConfigEditor to make your life simpler 
[image]

Then just go into the EndToEnd Tracing section and edit the configuration to suite your needs,

using tracing in conjuction with messaging will give you a way to relate the messageID( a guid) with the trace that is produced, and in some cases find the message that is giving you issues.

The other thing you can check is enabling the [ServiceAudit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-audit-wcf-security-events) tag in your ServiceBehavior settings, this will allow you to check security events that arise from your service.

[image]

Comment: where can I find SvcConfigEditor, I use visual studio 2017

Comment: right click on your web.config file and you will see the 'Edit WCF COnfigfutation'